# IF there´s a way of cloning an existing Alexa Skill in a local machine with the lambda functions included with ASK CLI v2

Tags: command-line-interface, alexa-skills-kit

I want to clone my existing Alexa skill in a local machine with the lambdas that handles the logic of it , in ASK CLI v1 I used the "clone" command and worked well but now in ASK CLI V2 I don't see this command and I can't clone my Alexa skill with the ASK INIT.

Is there´s a similar command to "clone" in ASK CLI V2? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Alexa hosted skill the instruction from @slawciu is totally correct.

For Non-hosted skill, please check the FAQ section in ask-cli: https://github.com/alexa/ask-cli/blob/develop/docs/FAQ.md#q-since-v2-ask-cli-removes-ask-clone-command-what-should-i-do-to-download-my-skill-project

In summary, you will need to:

```
 0. $ mkdir {folderName} ; cd {folderName}
 1. $ ask smapi export-package --skill-id {skillID}. 
    // this download skill-package folder to your local
 2. download your lambda source code into the folder.
 3. $ ask init
    //setup your skill project with a wizard command
```

After these steps, you can deploy your project by running **ask deploy**.

Comment: Thank you for your answer I did that and it worked!

Answer (score 2):

For Alexa-hosted skill You should run:

```
ask init --hosted-skill-id YOUR_SKILL_ID
```

According to the docs:

```
ask init [--hosted-skill-id <hosted-skill-id>]
         [--profile | -p <profile>]
         [--debug]
```

> **--hosted-skill-id** Optional. Specifying the Skill ID of an Alexa-hosted skill starts a workflow to **clone the skill** to the current directory.

You can find more interesting flags in the [documentation](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/smapi/ask-cli-command-reference.html#init-command).

When you use your own lambdas, according to [ASK CLI v1 to v2 Migration guide](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/smapi/ask-cli-v1-to-v2-migration-guide.html#remove-ask-clone):

> To migrate skill code hosted on AWS Lambda to a local machine, export the skill code from AWS Lambda. After the skill code has been downloaded, run ask init within the project directory to download Alexa [Skill Package](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/smapi/skill-package-api-reference.html) resources and set up the project for deployment using the ASK CLI.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but my skill isn't a hosted skill.